# @bindable changeHandler fires before bindings are done updating

Tags: javascript, aurelia

## The Code:

**App.js**

```js
export class App {
  constructor() {
    this.widgets = [{ name: 'zero'}, {name: 'one'}, {name:'two'}];
    this.shipment = { widget: this.widgets[1] };
  }
}
```

**App.html**

```html
<template>
  <require from="./widget-picker"></require>
  <require from="./some-other-component"></require>

  <widget-picker widget.bind="shipment.widget" widgets.bind="widgets"></widget-picker>
  <some-other-component widget.bind="shipment.widget"/>
</template>
```

**widget-picker.js**

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class WidgetPicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay, changeHandler: 'widgetChanged'  }) 
  widget;

  @bindable widgets;

  widgetChanged(widget) {
      // Use an Event Aggregator to send a message to SomeOtherComponent
      // to say that they should check their widget binding for updates.
  }
}
```

**widget-picker.html**

```html
<select value.bind="widget">
  <option repeat.for="widget of widgets" model.bind="widget">${widget.name}</option>
</select>
```

## The Problem:

The `@bindable`'s changeHandler fires the widgetChanged event before the binding gets updated to *App.js* and its `this.shipment.widget`.

So when the Event Aggregator message goes out, the previous value is still set on `this.shipment.widget'.

## Question:

**Is there a way to make `@bindable`'s changeHandler wait until all the bindings that will be updated for @bindable are done?**

Or is there another callback I can use?  Maybe a changedHandler (past tense)?

I did try to add `change.delegate="widgetChanged"` to the `select`, hoping that the `delegate` option would make it slower, but it still fires before the update is fully rolled out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could push the work you need to do onto the micro task queue:

```js
import {bindable, bindingMode, inject, TaskQueue} from 'aurelia-framework';

@inject(TaskQueue)
export class WidgetPicker {
  @bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.twoWay, changeHandler: 'widgetChanged'  }) 
  widget;
  @bindable widgets;

  constructor(taskQueue) {
    this.taskQueue = taskQueue;
  }

  widgetChanged(widget) {
    this.taskQueue.queueMicroTask(
      () => {
        // Use an Event Aggregator to send a message to SomeOtherComponent
        // to say that they should check their widget binding for updates.
      });
  }
}
```

This will ensure it occurs during the same "turn" of the event loop (as opposed to doing something like `setTimeout(...)`).

Comment: This worked perfectly!  Thank you very very much.  I LOVE Aurelia's binding system.

Comment: Is this still the best way to do this @JeremyDanyow ? Thank you!