# Trigger callback after bindings reevaluate in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

I'm building a drag-and-drop workspace, similar to the ones you find for making mockups. I have a workspace custom element that has a larger, nested element that can be zoomed and panned. Therefore, I need to carefully track size and position data of the workspace and all contained elements.

In my attached event of my custom element, I programatically set the height and width of the workspace as a JavaScript object, which is bound to the css in the view:

**workspaceCustomElement.js**

```
export class WorkspaceCustomElement {

    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    attached() {
        this.workspace.size = {
            height: this.element.height * 5,
            width: this.element.width * 5
        }
    }
}
```

**workspaceCustomElement.html**

```
<div css="height: ${workspace.height}px; width: ${workspace.width}px; 
    left: ${(element.clientWidth - workspace.width)/2}px; 
    top: ${(element.clientHeight - workspace.height)/2}px;"></div>
```

Now I'm running into problems trying to grab the positions of my child elements. I have attached callbacks on them as well, but they are being evaluated *before* the attached callback above, and so the css binding hasn't been evaluated, and the size and positions are wrong.

**I need to add a callback *after* the `attached()` has been evaluated and the bindings have been updated.** I can accomplish this by using a `setTimeout` hack, but I have no confidence that this will always work.

```
attached() {
    this.workspace.size = {
        height: this.element.height * 5,
        width: this.element.width * 5
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        let components = this.element.querySelectorAll('.component');
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(components, (component) => {
            let model = component.model;
            model.position = { 
                x: component.clientLeft,
                y: component.clientTop
            };
        }
    }, 0)
}
```

Is there a better, more reliable way to queue an instruction after the next binding update?

Comment: How about using Aurelia's `TaskQueue`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36049391/is-there-a-callback-or-promise-for-aurelia-show-bind

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best practices is to add a task to the `TaskQueue`. Under the hood, the binding engine uses the `TaskQueue` itself, so adding a new task will queue it behind the binding updates.

**workspaceCustomElement.js**

```
export class WorkspaceCustomElement {

    constructor(element, queue) {
        this.element = element;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    attached() {
        this.workspace.size = {
            height: this.element.height * 5,
            width: this.element.width * 5
        }
        this.queue.queueMicroTask(() => {
            let components = this.element.querySelectorAll('.component');
            Array.prototype.forEach.call(components, (component) => {
                let model = component.model;
                model.position = { 
                    x: component.clientLeft,
                    y: component.clientTop
                };
            }
        });
    }
}
```

See here for more information: [TaskQueue API](http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/api/aurelia/task-queue/latest/class/TaskQueue)

Answer (score 3):

you could create a binding behavior that invokes a callback of your choosing whenever the binding updates the target (the DOM element/custom-element/custom-attribute).

Here's an example: https://gist.run?id=28c0fedb21b5d8100913d3bc5500499f

**target-updated.js**

```js
export class TargetUpdatedBindingBehavior {
  bind(binding, source, callback) {
    // override the binding's updateTarget method.  add logic to invoke
    // the callback passed as a parameter to the binding behavior.
    binding.standardUpdateTarget = binding.updateTarget;
    binding.targetUpdatedCallback = callback;
    binding.updateTarget = function(value) {
      this.standardUpdateTarget(value);
      this.targetUpdatedCallback(this.target, this.targetProperty, value);
    };
  }

  unbind(binding, source) {
    // revert the binding to it's original state.
    binding.updateTarget = binding.standardUpdateTarget;
    binding.standardUpdateTarget = null;
    binding.targetUpdatedCallback = null;
  }
}
```

http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/binding/latest/binding-binding-behaviors

@MathewJamesDavis's answer is perfectly valid, I'm just offering this as a second option.

Comment: wow cool, in my case, wouldn't this be a tricky implementation since I'm actually triggering an event on an array of elements?

Comment: This is genious, I'm using this technique in many places. Basically everywhere, when I don't want direct binding, just being triggered if something changed.